# Update installed software

Tags: apt, updates, 15.04, software-center, update-manager

How can I update software already installed on my system?

I regularly get system updates, but Software I additionally installed (e.g. [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/), [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/), etc.) would not get updated.

The newest version of LibreOffice is 5, still I have version 4 on my system.
When I start Mendeley I get the following message:

> A newer version of Mendeley Desktop is available. Use Ubuntu's
>   Software Updater or your package manager to update.

Why the software won't update using the `Software Updater`?

Comment: I think it may depend pon which version of Ubuntu you are running, and which version of LibreOffice (or Mendeley) has been incorporated into the archives.  You can add the LibreOffice ppa directly to your system `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:libreoffice/ppa`, then run update and upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Ubuntu's built in `updater-manager` (not the `software center` nor `apt-get update`)? Usually all software updates for third-party software is sent through it.

Sorry I cannot be of more help, but that's the only method I know of.